# Reducing Firebase realtime database payload

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My goal is to reduce the amount of traffic between the client (iOS/Android) and the Firebase Realtime Database server.

My understanding is that By enabling Disk persistence, the following listener will only download the “changed” or “new” children under the users/uid node.  Even after an app restart.

```
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
let ref = Database.database().reference()
ref.child(“users”).child(user.uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in…
// Only changed data will be sent/received and stored in a local cache
}
```

However, I’ve read this may not be the case - that in fact the entire node under users/uid will be re-downloaded every time the app is started.

see article https://pamartinezandres.com/lessons-learnt-the-hard-way-using-firebase-realtime-database-c609b52b9afb

Can someone who understands the Disk Persistence features confirm if enabling the disk persistence feature will in fact reduce the amount of data being downloaded from the Firebase server?

Clarification - I would like to confirm if enabling disk persistence behaves the way I believe it does. I'm expecting the data from that node to download only a single time and store locally, not every time the app is opened.  If the data changes, my understanding is *only the diff is downloaded.

Comment: If you run that code, it will in fact download the nodes contained within users/uid_x. However, that's usually a tiny amount of data - it could be just a couple of child nodes name and favorite_food for example. I would suggest either posting your structure or giving us an idea of how much data is being stored in that node so we can understand the use case. It may be a case where denormalizing the data is the right move.

Comment: Clarification, it's not about the amount of data - I would like to confirm if enabling disk persistence behaves the way I believe it does.  I'm expecting the data from that node to download only a single time and store locally, not every time the app is opened.

Comment: Understood. The documentation is pretty clear on that *When you enable disk persistence, your app writes the data locally to the device so your app can maintain state while offline, **even if the user or operating system restarts the app.*** That being said, if the app 'goes online' it will automatically reconnect and synchronize any changes  - so that technically means it may download that node each time upon app start, if there are changes to the node, and the unit is online.

Comment: Did you implement this change? Did it reduce the amount of data being downloaded? I'd be very interested. Thx